# Custom type conversion in Karate

Tags: cucumber, karate, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

As Karate supports [type conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion), I was wondering if it is possible to write a custom type conversion in such a way that I could write something similar to this in my .feature file

```
customType customTypeResponse = response
```

which should have the same semantic as

```
yaml yamlResponse = response
```

but for customType instead of yaml.

I think I found the [code enabling the custom type conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Script.java#L604). But I am not sure about the extensibility.

Thus the shortest way might be to use the [Java interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-interop) enabling something like this

```
def customTypeResponse = CustomType.convert(response)
```

Please let me know of any possibiliy of type conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I strongly suggest just using Java interop and not [complicating it further for now](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/398). Maybe in the future we'll have a better way to do contribute custom syntax (hint: look for the `Plugin` interface and how `karate-robot` uses it).